# Passing an id when using filterContentForSearchText

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using filterContentForSearchText to search through a table view. The search works great but when I select a row, I have it send the ID for that row to my destination view controller. When I do the search, it still sends the ID of what the row was before I searched. I understand exactly what the problem is but I can't figure out how to fix it. This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];

    searchResults = [[projectArray valueForKey:@"clientName"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

And

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CategorySegue"]) {
    TimeCategoryViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSNumber *pid = [[projectArray objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"pid"];


        dvc.selectedProject = [searchResults objectAtIndex:pid];
    } else {
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSNumber *pid = [[projectArray objectAtIndex:path.row] valueForKey:@"pid"];
        dvc.selectedProject = pid;
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to add an ID to the search results so that I can pass it to the dvc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `searchResults` contains only the "clientName" for each object
and not the "full information".
I would suggest to make `searchResults` a "subarray" of `projectArray`:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"clientName CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
    searchResults = [projectArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Then you can access either `projectArray` or `searchResults` in `prepareForSegue`:

```
if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSNumber *pid = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:path.row] objectForKey:@"pid"];
    dvc.selectedProject = pid;
} else {
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSNumber *pid = [[projectArray objectAtIndex:path.row] objectForKey:@"pid"];
    dvc.selectedProject = pid;
}
```

(Of course you have also to adjust `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to this change.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I knew there was a way to do that, I just wasn't sure how.